# Unclosable activity for exams( Android )

Tags: java, android

I want to build an android application for exam purposes, when the user click "START EXAM" there are some conditions that should be happen on the app:

1. Can not use clipboard (copy,cut,paste)
2. Can not switch to the another app
3. Disable navigation button (back, home, and etc.)

which are java methods / xml configuration for those requirements?